# How to make virtual optical disk on Windows10

Tags: dvd-burning

I'm developing a application to write data to DVD. However my PC doesn't optical disk to write data to DVD. So I can't test my software

I know some software as ultralISO, it can make virtual disk. But it seem can't write data to virtual disk.

Could you let me know how to make a virtual optical disk on win 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by KernSafe TotalMounter